# Which statistical test should I use to determine the correlation between the independent and dependent variables in my experiment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

I am testing the reaction type of female birds (which can be + or -) and the length of reaction of females (in seconds) to male birds depending on the color of their feathers (highly colorful or not colorful) and their loudness (loud or quiet).

**Independent Variables** --> Male Bird Color (binary), Male Bird Loudness (binary)

**Dependent Variables** --> Female Reaction Types (binary), Female Reaction Length (continuous)

Which statistical test should I use to find the correlation strength of my data for these 4 variables?

Comment: It depends on your experimental design.  Could you provide some information about how you went about selecting experimental subjects and measuring or observing their behaviors?

Comment: "Colorful" males had a high feather color index while "not colorful" males were albino. Sound frequency was used to differentiate between "loud" and "quiet" male birds.

Female bird reaction length was measured with a timer if the reaction type was + (if a reaction occurred). If there was no reaction (-), the time was recorded as 0 seconds.

Comment: Please add extra information to your question rather than replying in comments. Coding  a lack of  reaction  as an instantaneous reaction seems bizarre on the face of it, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard analysis would be some kind of linear regression. In this case, since your response variables are related but have different types, you'll get strongest results from a flexible multivariate generalized linear model. At this time, I only know of R packages for such analysis: `mcglm` for quasi-likelihood models and `mcmcglm` for a Bayesian approach. There might be others out there too. Note that the learning curve on both can be steep, especially if you don't already have a strong statistical background.